# How to separate slices to be independent frames in multiple slices h264 stream?

Tags: h.264

I have a 4-slices h264 stream, which looks like

```
0x000001[sps] 0x000001[pps] 0x000001[IDR] 0x000001[IDR] 0x000001[IDR] 0x000001[IDR]
```

How to separate each slice to be a frame with 1/4 height, maybe look like

```
0x000001[sps] 0x000001[pps] 0x000001[IDR] 0x000001[sps] 0x000001[pps] 0x000001[IDR] 0x000001[sps] 0x000001[pps] 0x000001[IDR] 0x000001[sps] 0x000001[pps] 0x000001[IDR]
```

I have tried to modify the *first_mb_in_slice* in the slice header to be `0`, the height pic_height_in_map_units_minus1 from 119 to 29 and insert sps and pps before each slice.

I got 2 slices to decode success but another 2 slices were broken for each frame.

How do I fix it?
Thanks for any help.